# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: modalInstanceProvider <- modalInstance <- modalCtrl with the latest ui bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

EDIT - as the code below is, the modal will work - my issue was I had included ng-app and ng-controller in my HTML template for my modal, however they are not included in the below question.

I've my main controller, modal controller and my modal template HTML

Everything seems to be in order and I cannot for the life of me work out (or find out from stackoverflow) why I keep getting `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: modalInstanceProvider <- modalInstance <- modalCtrl` error.
BTW `$modal` is now depricated, it's `$ubiModal` now.

Main ctrl:

```
var module = angular.module("app", ["agGrid", "ngAnimate", "ngSanitize", "ngDialog", "ui.bootstrap"])

module.controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope", "dataService", "$timeout", "dateFilter", "ngDialog", "$http", "$uibModal", function ($scope, dataService, $timeout, dateFilter, ngDialog, $http, $uibModal) {

$scope.open = function () {

    var uibModalInstance= $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: "views/Modal.html",
        controller: "modalCtrl",
        show: true,
    })
};
}]);
```

my modal controller:

```
module.controller("modalCtrl", ["$scope", "ngDialog", "dataService", "$uibModalInstance", function ($scope, ngDialog, dataService, $uibModalInstance) {

//do stuff

}]);
```

and my HTML template:

```
 <div id="loginModal" class="modal show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" ng-click="closeThisDialog(); printArray()" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h1 class="text-center" style="text-align: center">Entities:</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="entity">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div ng-repeat="entity in entityArray | filter:entity">

                        <label>
                            <input style="float: left; margin-top: 5px" type="checkbox" ng-model="entityChecked" ng-change="getEntityFromModal(entity, entityChecked)" />
                            <span>{{entity}}</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button ng-click="okButtonEntity();" >OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$modalInstance` has since been changed (deprecated) to `$uibModalInstance` with the latest ui bootstrap (0.14.3). Also it should be `$modalInstance` with older versions.

i.e

```
module.controller("modalCtrl", ["$scope", "ngDialog", "dataService", "$uibModalInstance", 
                        function ($scope, ngDialog, dataService, $uibModalInstance) {
```

[Documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

> controller - a controller for a modal instance - it can initialize scope used by modal. Accepts the "controller-as" syntax in the form 'SomeCtrl as myctrl'; can be injected with $uibModalInstance

Comment: I've made the changes to reflect this in my question - still getting the same error : `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- modalCtrl`

Comment: @xeon48 Can you replicate the issue in a demo, possibly using a codepen or SO code snippet

Comment: @xeon48 What version of ui bootstrap you are using btw?

Comment: Hey got a plunkr working (or rather not working haha) here - http://plnkr.co/edit/2pLXtW9C6Nl65JtE1KpG?p=preview

Comment: @xeon48 Upgrade to 0.14.3, 0.14.2 seems half baked, it shows `$modalInstance`. I cant access plunker here, sorry. :(

Comment: OK I shall upgrade.  does jsfiddle work for you?  If the upgrade doesn't work out I can move it over to a fiddle?

Comment: codepen - codepen.io/anon/pen/GpGvBx problem is I can't include my HTML template as I can only see the ability to include one HTML file.. :S  HTML is above if you can utilize it?

Comment: @xeon48 you can place html inside script tag with `text/ng-template` type tag and use that as url

Comment: @xeon48 It works here.. http://codepen.io/pramodsankarl/pen/OyEjea. After changing it to 14.3. You need to use bootstrap tpls.js. Your issue is that you missed `$` before modalInstance. Actually it has only been deprecated and later will be removed

Comment: It works, the modal appears but i STILL get - rror: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- modalCtrl  what is going on?!

Comment: Here is the codepen with uibmodalinstance and 14.3. http://codepen.io/pramodsankarl/pen/vNreBj

Comment: @xeon48 Can you please check both the code pens i pasted in comments above. Check the console as well. I had wrong pen before.

Comment: @xeon48 Sorry i cant access it. Did you check the demos? aren't they working for you? You must be missing some stuffs. Use 14.3 boostrap tpls file, use angular proper version instead of beta, make sure you dont have any typoes. 14.2 you need to use `$modalInstance` that version is half baked.

Comment: Yep demos working...... It must be something else in my code, I'm totally stumped.  Seeing as the modal appears and it works in codepen I'm going to accept this as an answer.  Thanks for your time, I'll go through my code on Monday!  Maybe in your answer you could mention about 0.14.3 in place of 0.14.2?

Comment: Sure il update my answer. If u can replicate the issue pease put in a code pen and share it.

Comment: Found the error, although I posted my modal.html template without ng-app or ng-controller, I obviously hadn't remembered to save it.... So I needed to remove these from the template, as I believe they are automatically assigned via the `controller` option in uibModal